# Case insensitivity for DB Collation - does it affect performance?

Tags: database, collation

Earlier on while I was working on my databases, I wondered if using a case sensitive collation like `utf8_bin` would increase performance over case insensitive collaction like `utf8_general_ci` (examples are from MySQL).

Does anyone have any comment on this? What about databases other than MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a binary collation will be faster then others. How much, I can't say.

A binary sort or compare is simpler than dealing with case (+ accent, kanatype and width in SQL Server).